# using antlr4 for checking user input in a java code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, user-input, antlr4

I have a `.g4` file for my grammar and it works fine.

In my java program, user input must follow some rules which are the rules in the `.g4` file.

how can I use it in my java code to check if the user input is valid?

BTW, my IDE is `IntelliJ IDEA`.

here is my antlr code:

```
grammar CFG;


/*
 * Parser Rules
 */
    cfg: (rull NewLine)+;
    rull: Variable TransitionOperator sententialForm (Or sententialForm)*;
    sententialForm: ((Variable | Literal)+) | Landa;


 /*
  * Lexer Rules
  */

  Literal:  [a-z];
  Variable: [A-Z];
  TransitionOperator: '->';
  Or: '|';
  OpenParenthesis: '(';
  CloseParenthesis: ')';
//  Star: '*';
//  Plus: '+';
  Landa: 'λ';
  WhiteSpace: ' ' -> skip;
  NewLine: '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty easy to do: set up your parsing pipeline as usual:

```cs
using Antlr4.Runtime;
using Antlr4.Runtime.Tree;

public void MyParseMethod() {
      String input = "your text to parse here";
      ICharStream stream = CharStreams.fromstring(input);
      ITokenSource lexer = new CFGLexer(stream);
      ITokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
      MyGrammarParser parser = new CFGParser(tokens);
      // parser.BuildParseTree = true;
      IParseTree tree = parser.cfg();
}
```

(here written in C#) and once the parse run is done check [getNumberOfSyntaxErrors()](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Parser.java#L419) to see if there was an error in the input. For more finegrained handling set up your own error listener and collect the produced errors.